# Magento 2 display custom input radio in checkout page and save into sales_order table

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, input

I am trying to display with custom input radio button in checkout page as like below image and trying to save in **Sales_order** table. Here I am able to display the input radio button in checkout page and I'm created custom filed in **sale_order** table but I can't understand how can i save this input value.
Can any one please help on this.

image:[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please check with below url, which already done how to store data after place order :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51319902/magento-2-add-a-custom-input-field-on-chackout-forrm-and-save-it

**I hope its work for you..**